# React-mdl Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router> The website is not getting Routed

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router

> main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import home from './home';
import about from './about';
import menu from './menu';
import gallery from './gallery';
import franchise from './franchise';

const Main = () => (

    <Switch>

        <Route exact path ="/" component={home} />
        <Route  path ="/about" component={about} />
        <Route  path ="/menu" component={menu} />
        <Route  path ="/gallery" component={gallery} />
        <Route  path ="/franchise" component={franchise} /> 


    </Switch>
)
export default Main;
```

> nav.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Layout, Header, Navigation, Drawer, Content} from 'react-mdl';
import Main from './main';
export default class CustomNavbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
<div className="demo-big-content">
    <Layout>
        <Header title="CHEFSTYLE" scroll>

            <Navigation>
                <Link href="/" to="/">Home</Link>
                <Link href="/about" to="/about">About</Link>
                <Link href="/menu">Menu</Link>
                <Link href="/gallery">Gallery</Link>
                <Link href="/franchise">Franchise</Link>
            </Navigation>

        </Header>
        <Drawer title="CHEFSTYLE">
            <Navigation>
                <Link href="/" to="/">Home</Link>
                <Link href="/about" to="/about">About</Link>
                <Link href="/menu">Menu</Link>
                <Link href="/gallery">Gallery</Link>
                <Link href="/franchise">Franchise</Link>
            </Navigation>
        </Drawer>
        <Content>
            <div className="page-content" />
            <Main/>
        </Content>
    </Layout>
</div>  )

  }
}
```

**Error: Invariant failed: You should not use  outside a 
invariant
D:/pandemic/pandemicmateria/kupsmaterial/node_modules/tiny-invariant/dist/tiny-invariant.esm.js:11
(anonymous function)
D:/pandemic/pandemicmateria/modules/Link.js:84**
**I'm Using react-mdl for UI in react if i use Router tag instead of Switch in main.js and if i enclose navigation tag with Router tag in nav.js means i'm not getting any error but i'm not getting output... i mean the page is not routing with respect to links**

Comment: add your index.js file and let me know

Comment: I think you might missing `<BrowserRouter>` wrapper from you render. That's why you are getting that error. `<Link`> should be inside of a `<Router>` component, that's why you are getting that error message. Or you added somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Adding BrowserRouter in Index.js as bellow, worked for me.

```
ReactDOM.render (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only access your routes using Link if your whole application is in your Router.

```
<BrowserRouter>
<Layout>
        <He....

</Layout>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Dear sir I did that also BrouserRouter as Router... In that I'm not getting any error but The page is not getting routed...

Comment: where are you using your Router tag ??? please update your code.

Comment: you can refer my react project as well for better understanding with react router.https://github.com/karenaprakash/navbar-example.git